# Why does malloc work with zero size?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

   char* p;
   p = (char*)malloc(0);
   scanf("%s", p);
   printf("%s", p);
   free(p);
}
```

Could someone explain to me why every word i am typing via terminal is printed out to the user? I have `malloc(0)`. Isn't supposed when i try to `scanf` to give me a `segmentation fault`?

Edit

Why this gives me a compilation error:

```
p = malloc(sizeof(char) * 2)
```

when i try to to avoid `(void*)`

```
error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'char *' with an rvalue of type 'void *'
```

Comment: you are casuing undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a duplicate somewhere, but all I can find is about automatic arrays.

Comment: maybe undefined, but implementation defined behaviour depending on compiler/runtime.

Comment: i did search the web for some time before writing in stack overflow. I couldn't find a specific answer why this particular piece of code works

Comment: @t0mm13b: writing to it is still UB.

Comment: @Korpel: it *doesn't work*. You were just lucky. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Comment: Also, as usual [please don't cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3233393).

Comment: whyd you think scanning a string of arbitrary length into a buffer of size 1 byte is going to be any more defined than a buffer of size 0 bytes?

Comment: @TomTanner you are correct. I am doing exactly the same but in the first case i had a "buffer" of 0 size and after that i had one of 1 byte. So yeah same case. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: If the last line (without the cast) triggers a compilation error, it's probably because you're using a C++ compiler instead of a C one. In C there's a well-defined implicit conversion to and from `void*`.

Comment: @Quentin that was the issue thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C Standard for [malloc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html) explicitly specifies this:

> If the size of the space requested is 0, the behavior is
>   implementation-defined: the value returned shall be either a null
>   pointer or a unique pointer.

And for the return value from `malloc`:

> If size is 0, either a null pointer or a unique pointer that can be
>   successfully passed to free() shall be returned. Otherwise, it shall
>   return a null pointer and set errno to indicate the error.

In regards to segmentation fault from the call to `scanf`, that is purely on the basis of the implementation and runtime behaviour of the environment, just down to luck rather than anything, the next time it is run, it *may* crash with segmentation fault.

Comment: You are actually citing the POSIX standard, not the C standard. Although the POSIX standard contains a lot of copy / paste from the C standard.

Comment: @Lundin - the language in the C standard is largely the same, it's just under a different section (7.22.3): "If the size of
the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined: either a null pointer
is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the
returned pointer shall not be used to access an object."

Comment: Note: The C standard does not specify to set `errno`.  Recommend to added citations to the quote sections.

Answer (score 3):

The C standard 9899:2011 7.22.3 states that:

> If the space cannot be allocated, a null pointer is returned. If the size of
>   the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.

Meaning that what is returned from malloc is *implementation-defined behavior*. You'll have to read your specific compiler documentation to see what it does in your case: return a null pointer or a non-zero pointer pointing at 0 bytes of data (likely a random garbage location).

In either case, the returned pointer is not pointing at a valid memory location. So if you attempt to write to it, you'll invoke undefined behavior. Meaning anything can happen: the program can crash & burn, or it can seem to work correctly and crash one month later, or anything else.

> Why this gives me a compilation error: `p = malloc(sizeof(char) * 2)`

Because you are trying to compile C code with a C++ compiler. Don't do that. Some C++ compilers have an option you can set to compile with a C compiler instead.

---

Side note about an inconsistency in the C standard:

The standard Annex J actually list the above as unspecified behavior. I suspect this must be an error in Annex J, as the normative text cited above clearly states that this is implementation-defined. 7.22.3 is normative and Annex J is informative, so I would just ignore Annex J.

Comment: @Quentin You are right... fixed.

Comment: Now that's an excellent answer, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

From [opengroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html) -

> If the size of the space requested is 0, the behavior is implementation-defined: the value returned shall be either a null pointer or a unique pointer.

Nothing is allocated by `malloc(0)`. So , when you try to take input using `scanf`  you invoke *undefined behaviour* .

> Isn't supposed when i try to scanf to give me a segmentation fault?

No , it's not necessary when you have *UB* . Maybe you are not that lucky to get segmentation fault and got desired output( *which may confuse*).

Comment: Implementation-defined behavior is not undefined behavior.

Comment: @Lundin I didn't say that . I said when OP tries to take input using `scanf` ,it invokes UB.  If it may have sound ambiguous , sorry for that .

Comment: @Lundin I made it clear . That may have created misunderstanding :-)

Comment: Much clearer now indeed :)