# why is it possible to access memory beyond the amount i malloc

Tags: c, malloc, buffer-overflow

I was testing a c program in order to see what happens in a loop if inside a string allocated with malloc i replace \0 with any other character. What I thought it gave me as output is either segmentation fault or access to another area of ​​memory since malloc returns a memory area of ​​a specific number of bytes. However,
I found out some strange behavior with malloc. Here is my code:

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(char *s)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(s[i])
        i++;
    s[i++] = '5';
    return ;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *s = malloc(4);
    printf("%p\t%s\n", s, s);

    strcpy(s, "test");
    printf("%p\t%s\n", s, s);

    foo(s);
    printf("%p\t%s\n", s, s);

    foo(s);
    printf("%p\t%s\n", s, s);

    return 0;
}
```

idk even if i allocate for 4 bytes in the foo function the character are added correctly in the second call of foo().
this is the output:

```
0x131606960
0x131606960     test
0x131606960     test5
0x131606960     test55
```

But then i changed the s declaration with `malloc(1)` and still produce the same output, strcpy also works fine (Why this happen? shouldn't it give segmentation fault? Maybe the OS operates under the hood in this case?).
The strange behavior occurs when I replace with `malloc(0)`, that, according to the specification [malloc(0)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html) have to return a NULL pointer but with the possibility to pass pointer to the free() function. Thus, it's basically the same thing as doing

`char *s = NULL;`

instead produce this output:

```
0x146704080
0x146704080     test
0x146704080     test5
0x146704080     test55
```

Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: When you use more space than is allocated to you, it is ***Undefined Behavior***.  A Seg Fault is one possible outcome, so is Nasal Demons, and so is seemingly-correct behavior.  There are NO GUARANTEES when you use invalid memory.

Comment: try out https://linux.die.net/man/3/efence

Comment: or try valgrind,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022335/whats-the-point-of-malloc0 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132273/what-does-malloc0-return https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684595/behaviour-of-malloc0 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346622/why-does-malloc-work-with-zero-size https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073157/zero-size-malloc

Answer (score 2):

[This `malloc` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) might be useful to read:

> If size is zero, the behavior of malloc is implementation-defined. For example, a null pointer may be returned. Alternatively, a non-null pointer may be returned; but such a pointer should not be dereferenced, and should be passed to free to avoid memory leaks.

So `malloc` *may* return `NULL`, or it may not. If it doesn't return `NULL` then the pointer that is returned may not be used by anything else than passing to `free`.

If you dereference the pointer then you will have *undefined behavior*.

---

Furthermore, the allocation

```
char *s = malloc(4);
```

is not enough to fit a four-character string, as it doesn't have space for the null-terminator.

You also print the contents of the allocated memory, but `malloc` doesn't initialize its memory in any way, the contents is *indeterminate* and should be seen as "garbage" or "random". More specifically, there's no guarantee that it will contain a string terminator within those four bytes, which means your printing of its contents is likely to go out of bounds and also lead to undefined behavior.

Then in the `foo` function you will *overwrite* the null-terminator, leaving it as merely a sequence of character but not a string in the sense that C thinks it is. That means the next call to `foo` will go out of bounds of the memory looking for the non-existing terminator, and again lead to undefined behavior.

I recommend you take some time to refresh your text-books and what they say about pointers, strings and `malloc`. And if they say that `malloc(0)` should return a `NULL` pointer, you might consider other books.

Comment: that was the purpose of the foo() function. Go out of bounds on allocated memory and see what happens.

Comment: @username Unfortunately, "see what happens" is kind of pointless with undefined behavior. It might seem to work, it might crash your program, corrupt your OS, or it might set fire to your cat. Well maybe not the last, but with UB there's just no point in see what happens.